# Modify a table in .txt file using python

Tags: python

I have a .txt file containing a set of data organized as follow:

```
(id1) (name1) (x coordinate1) (y coordinate1) (value1)
(id2) (name2) (x coordinate2) (y coordinate2) (value2) 
(id3) (name3) (x coordinate3) (y coordinate3) (value3) 

.....
```

Now I want to move all (names) from column 2 to column 4. The code I wrote is this:

```
with open("C:\\path\\to\\input\\file.txt","r") as f:
    rows = list(f)
    table = [["."],["."],["."],["."],["."],["."]]*len(rows)
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        row = rows[i].split(" ")
        table[6*i] = row[0]+" "
        table[6*i+1] = row[2]+" "
        table[6*i+2] = row[3]+" "
        table[6*i+3] = row[1]+" "
        table[6*i+4] = row[4]
        table[6*i+5] = "\n"
    with open("C:\\path\\to\\output\\file.txt","w") as o:
        o.writelines(table)
```

it performs the task but the output contains a blank line after each row. I have tried hours to get rid of them but I cannot figure out how to get a correct output. The wrong output is this:

```
(id1) (x coordinate1) (y coordinate1) (name1) (value1)

(id2) (x coordinate2) (y coordinate2) (name2) (value2) 

(id3) (x coordinate3) (y coordinate3) (name3) (value3) 

.....
```

Comment: So you add a line break to each row and are wondering why there is an extra line break. Have you tried *not* adding a line break?

Comment: `rows = list(f)` doesn't magically strip off the newlines from the input file. These stick around, and end up appended (in this case) to the last column (`row[4]`). Hence there already is an newline.

Comment: I'm just puzzled how `rows[i].split(" ")` does not end up splitting `(x coordinate1)` etc. Perhaps a sneaky non-standard space there.

Comment: (x coordinate) is a numeric value, I wrote that way just to explain the structure of my table. Anyway if I remove the line break I got this error: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list"

Comment: If your file contains space separated values, you might get better results using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and register a custom (space delimited) dialect. Then you can use the csv's reader and writer to access, modify and save your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a line break, try removing this line:

`table[6*i+5] = "\n"`

Since the file you are pulling in has line breaks they get automatically included with the last item in your list.

Edit:
Your source file might be a little wonky, you can also change that last line to be:

`table[6*i+5] = ""`

Comment: Explanation is wrong. Writing to a file will NOT automatically add linebreaks. Not even when using [writelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapper#io.IOBase.writelines)

Comment: If I delete that line I get this error: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list"...

Comment: @MikeScotty whoops! didn't drink my tea yet this morning, all fixed :)

Comment: @Alessandro actually if I run your code, I'm not seeing the same issue.  I don't get extra line breaks.  Let me try something

Comment: @sniperd solved! I had to simply remove a string form the table initialization, and modify the [6*i] to [5*i]

Answer (score 0):

When you read the data from the file, the new lines are present in the data, hence, when you write manipulate and then rewrite the data in another file, it automatically the new lines. Hence there is no need to manually add the new lines yourself since that will just add extra unnecessary new lines(which is the problem we are facing).

So you must remove this line -`table[6*i+5] = "\n"`. I hope this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, you are adding a line break to each line, but your column 4 already contains a line break, resulting in 2 breaks.

However there is another problem with your code. `file.writelines` expects a list of strings, usually with a line break at the end of each. But you create a table which is instead a long list of lists, each containing 1 string:

```
table = [["."],["."],["."],["."],["."],["."]]*len(rows)
```

You then replace these sub-lists, one by one, with strings:

```
table[6*i] = row[0]+" "   # etc.
```

If any are not replaced, `writelines` will raise an error because there is a list where it expects a string. So you need to make some additional adjustments to make your existing code work:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    rows = list(f)
table = ["", "", "", "", ""]*len(rows)
for i in range(len(rows)):
    row = rows[i].split(" ")
    table[5*i] = row[0]+" "
    table[5*i+1] = row[2]+" "
    table[5*i+2] = row[3]+" "
    table[5*i+3] = row[1]+" "
    table[5*i+4] = row[4]
with open("output.txt","w") as o:
    o.writelines(table)
```

However a better way of doing this would be to build the table one row at a time, like this:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    table = []
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip().split(" ")  # strip removes any line breaks / extra spaces
        table.append([row[0], row[2], row[3], row[1], row[4]])

with open("output.txt","w") as o:
    o.writelines(" ".join(row) + "\n" for row in table)
```

Better still, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module which is designed for this and will deal with the newlines automatically:

```
import csv
with open("input.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w", newline="") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=" ")
    for row in csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=" "):
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[2], row[3], row[1], row[4]])
```

or [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("input.txt", sep=" ", header=None)[[0, 2, 3, 1, 4]] \
    .to_csv("output.txt", sep=" ", header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pitty you are required to use Python. You could do it command line (assuming your data is a in a file `data.txt`):

```
sed -e 's/) (/);(/g' data.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $1 ";" $3 ";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $2}' | sed -e 's/;/ /g'
```